# pandas groupby on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a data set which contains state code and its status.

```
  code  status
1   AZ  a
2   CA  b
3   KS  c
4   MO  c
5   NY  d
6   AZ  d
7   MO  a
8   MO  b
9   MN  b
10  NV  a
11  NV  e
12  MO  f
13  NY  a
14  NY  a
15  NY  b
```

I want to filter out this data set which code contains only `a` status and count how many they have. Example output will be,

```
  code  status  
1   AZ  a   
2   MO  a   
3   NY  a   

    AZ =1   MO = 1  NY =2
```

I used `df.groupyby("code").loc[df.status == 'a']` but didn't have any luck.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: you could also group by multiple columns, even though its not explicitly what you asked for with `df.groupby(['code','status']).count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's filter the dataframe first for a, then groupby and count.

```
df[df.status == 'a'].groupby('code').size()
```

Output:

```
code
AZ    1
MO    1
NV    1
NY    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I also want to have multiple values, so I tried `df[df.status == 'a' or df.status == 'b'].groupby('code').size()` but I have keyerror. Do you have any idea why I get keyerror?

Comment: `df[df['status'].isin(['a','b'])].groupby('code').size()`  Or as you're trying: `df[(df['status'] == 'a') | (df['status'] == 'b')].groupby('code').size()`

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your dataset

```
data = [["AZ","CA", "KS","MO","NY","AZ","MO","MO","MN","NV","NV","MO","NY","NY" ,"NY"],
       ["a","b","c","c","d","d","a","b","b","a","e","f","a","a","b"]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T
df.columns = ["code","status" ]

df[df["status"] == "a"].groupby(["code", "status"]).size()
```

gives

```
code  status
AZ    a         1
MO    a         1
NV    a         1
NY    a         2
dtype: int64
```